# How to measure silence intervals

Tags: ios, audiokit

Hi my goal is to measure silence intervals (amplitude bellow specific Db) while someone is speaking but with very good precision like 5-10ms.  What i did is to schedule a timer that runs 1000 times per second and check AKFrequencyTracker amplitude and frequency properties and determine if this interval is "silence". Next time when some sound is detected (amplitude above specific value and frequency in 80-300Hz range) i measure the last silence interval. While this method works its not very precise. I have audio file that i play and has 100ms intervals but with this method i measure them as 90-160ms intervals. I tried tweaking some AKSettings but without success. I guess AKFrequencyTracker.amplitude can't be updated so fast ? Can someone give me advice how to improve it or maybe suggest another way how to measure more precise silence intervals. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried a NoiseGate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47601246/317461