# AudioKit: Noise gate

Tags: ios, audiokit

I'm trying to implement a simple noise gate if the amplitude is beyond a certain threshold using `AudioKit`.

I believe this should be simple and I just need to use the [AKAmplitudeTracker](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Analysis/Amplitude%20Tracker/AKAmplitudeTracker.swift) and set the output to zero, but I can't work out how to do the latter part.

[Source for AKAmplitudeTracker](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Analysis/Amplitude%20Tracker/AKAmplitudeTracker.swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you don't know how to set the output to zero.  I'll go ahead and write the most obvious answer first, send the output through a booster,

```
...tracker stuff...
let booster = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)
AudioKit.output = booster
```

and then wherever you poll the tracker, set

```
if tracker.amplitude > threshold {
   booster.gain = 1
}
```

Mind you, this will be very primitive and you'll have a better noise gate doing things at the DSP level, but this may be good enough for a proof of concept or test.

Comment: Hi @AureliusProchazka - thanks for the reply. You are right, after a while thinking about it I realised I was barking up the wrong tree to do what I wanted but thank you - I think what I didn't realise is you need to poll outside the Tracker like with a time interval.